# worklight get image blob from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm new to worklight, and i'm trying to get an image which is stored in mysql as a blob data. but i'm having trouble the picture won't show.
here is my code

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
  onSuccess: function(response){
    var result = response.invocationResult; //ini hasilnya
    if(result.isSuccessful){
      var data = result.resultSet;
      var text ='';
      $.each(data , function(index,item){
        var base64blob = item.picture;
        var image = document.createElement('img');
                image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+ base64blob;
                document.body.appendChild(image);
                ...
        text += '<img class="ui-li-thumb" src="' + 'data:image/jpg;base64,'+ base64blob + '"></img>';
        ...
  });
  $('#order_list').html(text);
        $('#order_list').listview('refresh');
    } else{
            alert("error");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapters returns only a JSON object.
A BLOB is a binary large object.
You need to convert the binary object to base64 before it is sent as the response.

Comment: how can I convert the binary object in mysql without php?

Comment: You can do it in multiple ways. In the adapter you can call JAVA code to convert the bolb into base64 or you can usr MySQL functions to_base64() and from_base64() that were added into mysql-5.6 or you could do it with JavaScript in the adapter, but that is not recommended.

Comment: If you find this question answered please resolve as answered.